# How to compress and tar a folder in Linux

Tags: linux, command, zip, tar

I am new to Linux, I have a folder called `stacey`.  How can I create a compressed tarball from this?

I can tar the folder with `tar -cvzf stacey.tar *`. But can I add the 7zip at the same time as so I have a compressed tarball called `stacey.tar.gz` ?

Comment: It's already gzip compressed thanks to your `-z`. You can verify this with `file stacey.tar`, and then simply rename it to add the missing extension

Comment: I think you had to make an effort to avoid finding an answer. Here are your duplicates: [Compress a folder with tar?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/46969), [How to compress the directory and its contents](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/185931), [How do I tar a directory of files and folders without including the directory itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/939982), [How to gzip all files in all sub-directories into one compressed file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12331633), [gzipping up a set of directories and creating a tar compressed file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3341131), etc.

Comment: This sort of question is best asked on Super User, since it is essentially a consumer-level computing problem. It could go onto Ubuntu or Unix & Linux.

Answer (score 12):

#### To make a compressed tar ball of the current directory

```
tar -cvz -f path_to_the_archive_to_be_created .
```

Example:

```
[user@machine temp]$ tar -cvz -f ~/dir1/temp.tar.gz .
```

The current directory (temp) is archived into `~/dir1/temp.tar.gz`

#### To make a compressed tar ball of a remote directory

```
tar -cvz -f path_to_the_archive_to_be_created -C path_to_the_remote_directory .
```

Example:

```
[user@machine ~]$ tar -cvz -f ~/dir1/temp.tar.gz -C ~/temp .
```

The directory ~/temp is archived into `~/dir1/temp.tar.gz`.

---

```bash
-c, --create  create a new archive
-v, --verbose  verbosely list files processed
-z, --gzip, --gunzip, --ungzip  filter the archive through gzip
-f, --file=ARCHIVE  use archive file or device ARCHIVE
-C, --directory=DIR  change to directory DIR
```

Answer (score 2):

Passing `-z` on the `tar` command will gzip the file, so you should name your file `stacey.tar.gz` (or `stacey.tgz`), not `stacey.tar`:

```
tar -cvzf stacey.tar.gz *
```

If you want to 7zip the file (instead of Gzip), remove the `-z`, keep `stacey.tar`, and run `7z stacey.tar` after the `tar` command completes:

```
tar -cvf stacey.tar *
7z a stacey.tar.7z stacey.tar
```

Or you can use a pipeline to do it in one step:

```
tar -cvf - * | 7z a -si stacey.tar.7z
```

7zip is more like `tar` in that it keeps an index of files in the archive. You can actually skip the `tar` step entirely and just use 7zip:

```
7z a stacey.7z *
```

Comment: I have put some of the useful linux commands here include how to unzip zip, tar.xz, .tar.gz etc here -> http://www.tech-ladder.com/2022/07/tech-laddercom-articles-and-snippets.html